# Reading data from Firebase using toObject / MyClass

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I try to read data from Firestore directly on MyClass format. It works fine when I read variable by variable but I wish to read directly the whole class.
When doing this:

```
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
            (this.application as MyApp).value = documentSnapshot.toObject<MyClass>()
        }
```

I have this error

> Type mismatch: inferred type is MyClass? but MyClass was expected

Any idea?

Comment: Make sure you use '=>' instead of '->'

Comment: Nope << Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) >>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It complains about [nullability](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) of class `MyClass`.

`?` after the class name means it should be nullable. Compare `MyClass?` and `MyClass`.

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#toObject(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) the method signature is:

```
public T toObject (Class<T> valueType)
```

And it

> Returns the contents of the document converted to a POJO or null if
> the document doesn't exist.

Kotlin considers it as non-null-safe. You can explicitly specify it by `!!` if you are certain about it being non-null:

```
(this.application as MyApp).value = documentSnapshot.toObject<MyClass>()!!
```

Be careful though, it can lead to [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) and is not considered as best practice.

Or as a better solution, you can make `value` of class `MyApp` nullable by specifying `value: MyClass?`.

Comment: Great! It works, a,d it makes me more clearer the nullability. Thanks!

Comment: Accept the answer then ;)